# Click event in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Is it possible to have click event inside the model and call it from different view below is my code,which have 2 view use same studenviewModel,now i want click event inside the model need help,if i use click event inside the studentViewModel it works but inside classModel its not working

```
function studentViewModel()
{
     self.studentDetails=ko.observaleArray([]);
    sum function to call ajax method
}

function classModel(data)
{
   get bind to class 

    self.getClassdetails=function()
     {
      }
}

 <div id="view1" data-role="view" class="student">

 <div>
  <div id="view2" data-role="view" class="student">
   <button data-bind="getClassdetails"><button>
  <div>

   ko.applybinding(new studentViewModel(),documentgetelementByClassName("student"))
```

Comment: You may be looking for knockout-postbox plugin. You are using Knockout V2.x?

Comment: yes i am using Knockout 3.3.0 v

Comment: Why have you added [tag:knockout-2.0] to your question then?

Comment: @connex sorry i didnt get you,so is it possible to get click function inside model

Comment: You can only call functions of the viewmodel innside the view that belongs to it. Outside of that view the function will not be available unless it is a parent viewmodel. To interact between two different viewmodels that have no nesting relation, you could use the messenger-subscriber pattern, using for example the `knockout-postbox` plugin.

Comment: @thanks,Is is possible to use the self.studentDetails=ko.observaleArray([]) inside classModel

Comment: No, it's the same with that. You can ofc always hand over properties from inside `studentViewModel` to other functions by passing it as a argument in a function call, for example `classModel(self.studentDetails)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a rough-up pseudo solution to illustrate the idea. You can cleanup the syntax and improve the class inter-dependency. The idea is to express the dependency of the viewa in your models:

```
function studentViewModel()
{
   --> self.classStudentBelongsTo = ... somehow inject this or new it here
   self.studentDetails=ko.observaleArray([]);
   sum function to call ajax method
}

function classModel(data)
{
   get bind to class 

    self.getClassdetails=function()
     {
      }
}

 <div id="view1" data-role="view" class="student">

 <div>
  <div id="view2" data-role="view" class="student">
   <button data-bind="--> classStudentBelongsTo.getClassdetails"><button>
  <div>

   ko.applybinding(new studentViewModel(),documentgetelementByClassName("student"))
```

Comment: @thanks ,but i am unable to understand it,please can u explain briefly..